# Is there a special name for linear irreducible polynomials (over the complex numbers)?

Tags: polynomials, terminology, irreducible-polynomials

According to the fundamental theorem of algebra every polynomial over the complex numbers can be factorized into the following form:
$$
c (x - r_1) (x - r_2) (x - r_3) \dots
$$
where $r_i$ are the roots of the polynomial.  Is there a special name for these $x - r_i$?

Searching the web is exceedingly difficult if you don't know the name of the thing you're searching for, so I wasn't successful with that.

Thanks!

Comment: What properties about them do you want to name? They're monic first degree polynomials. They're the irreducible factors over the complex numbers (up to units). They have other properties too.

Comment: @MarkS. It just feels to me as if there should be some common name for what polynomials can be factored into (here polynomial is used synonymous with polynomials over the complex numbers).

Comment: "Linear polynomials".

Comment: @davidlowryduda Linear polynomials can also have a factor before the $x$ ($a x + b$), but in the usual way of factoring polynomials all these are combined in a single one, which I called $c$ above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what polynomials can be factored into

If you don't care about constant multiples, they are the [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) [factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Polynomials) of the polynomial. If you do, they are the [monic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) irreducible factors.

(If you want to be a little confusing/cheeky and exploit [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain) of [polynomial rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring), they are also the [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) factors, but that is debatably further from the "what [something] can be factored into" idea.)

Comment: Thanks, "linear monic" is the term I searched for, even though it would have been nice to have a single word for that.